# I want to fadein a div onclick and fadeout div after a certain time automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, alert, fadein, fadeout

Actually my problem is, I want to `fadein` a `div` on `click` event, and `fadeout` that `div` after a certain time automatically.

I have  made some thing, but the `fadeout` function is not working. Here is my snippet:

```css
.alert-box {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
  padding: 20px 0;
  background-color: red;
  color: #fff;
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button>click me</button>


<div class="alert-box">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <div class="content">
    sample content
  </div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('button').click(function() {
      $('.alert-box').fadeIn('fast');
    });
    if ($('.alert-box').css('display') == 'block') {
      $('.alert-box').delay(1000).fadeOut('fast');
    }
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `setTimeout` for fadeout after 1 second

```
setTimeout (() => {
    $('.alert-box').fadeOut('fast');
}, 1000)
```

Removed the unnecesary code too.

```css
.alert-box {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
  padding: 20px 0;
  background-color: red;
  color: #fff;
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>click me</button>


<div class="alert-box">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <div class="content">
    sample content
  </div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('button').click(function() {
      $('.alert-box').fadeIn('fast');
      setTimeout(() => {
        if ($('.alert-box').css('display') == 'block') {
          $('.alert-box').delay(1000).fadeOut('fast');
        }
      }, 1000);
    });

  });
</script>
```

Comment: ohh thanks, it works.   could you explain how setTimeout works?

Comment: The setTimeout() method calls a function or evaluates an expression after a specified number of milliseconds. https://www.w3schools.com/Jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Comment: and whats wrong in this      if ($('.alert-box').css('display') == 'block') { $('.alert-box').delay(1000).fadeOut('fast');}                why its not working?

Comment: No issues in that code, you can use that as well(see updated answer),but this code gets executed right away, you need it to get executed after 1 second, so you need a settimeout

Comment: Please accept this answer if you are satisfied with it :) Helps other people know what worked for you :)

Comment: could you give me your any social account, i have another problem in js, that can't be explained here.

Comment: You can find me on fb. M there by the same name

Comment: m not using fb, do you have instagram account? drop your username.

Comment: Sorry thats a private account, You can post it on SO and send me the link to your question in the comments here. I will look into it and try to help you out :)]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56441183/how-to-use-scroll-when-i-resize-the-window

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/) right after [`fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/) with delay speed.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button').click(function() {
        $('.alert-box').fadeIn('fast').delay(1000).fadeOut('fast');
    });
});
```

```css
.alert-box{
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
        display: none;
        padding: 20px 0;
        background-color: red;
        color: #fff;
    }
    .close{
        position: absolute;
        right: 10px;
        top: 10px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>click me</button>


<div class="alert-box">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <div class="content">
        sample content
    </div>
</div>
```